# Tomcat user not relaying SSH key properly with Jenkins and Gitosis

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, jenkins, gitosis

I have a new setup of Jenkins running as a WAR deployment on a Tomcat6 server in Ubuntu.  I also have, on that same server, and install of Gitosis for all of my repositories.

I have been working on getting Jenkins to build the repositories, but have been unsuccessful in getting the SSH public key setup for Tomcat in my repo server.  I started out by logging in as Tomcat with the command `sudo su - tomcat6` and ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.  After that I copied the id_rsa.pub key to the keydir directory in the gitosis repo.

So here is the basic rundown of my command:

```
sudo su - tomcat6
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "tomcat6@trogdorsrv"
exit # Get back to my user
sudo cp /usr/share/tomcat6/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/gitosis-admin/keydir/tomcat6@trogdorsrv
```

My next step was to open the gitosis.conf file in the gitosos-admin repo and add my new user as the administrator of the repos:

```
vim ~/gitosis-admin/gitosis.conf
```

gitosis.conf:

```
[group buildserver]
writable = repo-name
members = tomcat6@trogdorsrv
```

I also have other members and the repo-name is the name of my actualy repo.  I then pushed the gitosis-admin repo up to the remote and commited some data to it from another repo user.

I am able to read and write to my repo from the other users, but when I try to use Tomcat I get an error that it can't login.  I tried logging in as Tomcat again and doing a git clone manually so that the git server's fingerprint was added to the known_hosts and when I did the clone it asked me for my git users password.

Soooo am I doing something wrong to get Jenkins SSH keys into Gitosis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I named my public key tomcat6@server in the keydir, whereas gitosis requires the file to be names tomcat6@server.pub to use it even though I did copy the public key.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a step:

After you copy your ssh pub key to the server, you need to add its contents to a file called

```
authorized_keys
```

in the ~/.ssh folder. Just do a simple `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on your target server, and you should be able to log in without a password.

Does this work?

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that.  Gitosis handles all of that for me when I push to the gitosis-admin repository.  For some reason it doesn't do that though, and if I manually add it to the authorized_keys I still can't get in.

Comment: Aah ok. I do not know much about Gitosis. I was looking it at from an ssh point of view. Have you tried `ssh-copy-id`? Even if Gitosis does not do it, at least ssh login should work.

Comment: You can see what my problem was from my answer below.  It turns out to simply be that I named the key wrong.

Comment: Thanks for putting back the answer! Good to know you got it working